# Upload Windows Server VM on Bluemix Virtual Machines?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Will it be possible to deploy an own Windows Server based VM to Bluemix? The team would like to deploy a previous version of ASP.NET not supported by the current cf buildpack. The plan is to deploy a Windows VM with all needed components and libraries to Bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

As reported on VM bluemix docs

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/index-gentopic4.html

> If you have a customized virtual machine (VM) image, or if you want to
>   create a VM from a snapshot that you took of another VM, you can
>   upload your own VM images within the Bluemix dashboard into a public
>   cloud.
>
> You can upload a local VM image file from your local file system or
>   from a VM image that is located in an external HTTP URL. Note: You can
>   upload VM images that are supported by OpenStack only. To check the
>   OpenStack prerequisites, see http://www.openstack.org/.